# Diff which folders are missing

Tags: windows, linux, bash, shell, diff

I have two folders each which contain a lot of subfolders. Most of the files and folders should be the same, but I want to be able to figure out which folders are missing.

For example:

```
Folder1/
    A/
        1.jpg
    B/
        2.jpg
    C/
        3.jpg
    D/
        4.jpg
```

and

```
Folder2/
    A/
        1.jpg
    E/
        2.jpg
    C/
        3.jpg
    D/
        4.jpg
```

Is there any way to know that "B" got deleted? I'm running windows, but I have cygwin installed so bash scripts, diff, or python/perl would work.

I know I can just "diff -q -r Folder1 Folder2" everything in both folders, but that takes FOREVER and spits out everything that's changed, including files in those folders, where I just need the folders themselves.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: How deep do you want to go? ie, do you mind if `A/B` got deleted?

Comment: Yeah I need to go all the way down the tree to the leaf nodes, but I really just need to know which "encompassing" nodes are deleted. I.e. if 1.jpg got deleted but also A got deleted, I really just need to know that I should delete "A" from the other folder.

Comment: Ah, that changes the problem quite a bit!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
diff -u <(cd Folder1 ; find | sort) <(cd Folder2 ; find | sort)
```

Some notes:

- This would include files that are added/removed, but not files that are merely modified. If you don't even want to include files that are added/removed, change `find` to `find -type d`, as herby suggests.
- If a given directory is added/removed, this will also list out all the files and directories *within* that directory. If that's a problem, you can address it by appending something like `| perl -ne 'print unless m/^\Q$previous\E\//; $previous = $_;'`.
- Barron's answer makes me realize that you didn't actually specify that you need the folders to be examined recursively. If you just need the very top level, you can change `find` to either `find -maxdepth 1` (or `find -maxdepth 1 -type d`) or `ls -d *` (or `ls -d */`), as you prefer.

Comment: I actually do need it recursively, just forgot to mention that :) Whoops!

Answer (score 2):

```
(cd Folder1 && find . -type d >/tmp/$$.1)
(cd Folder2 && find . -type d >/tmp/$$.2)
diff /tmp/$$.1 /tmp/$$.2
rm /tmp/$$.1 /tmp/$$.2
```

Comment: Well, `sort` is maybe not bad idea, too.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I hacked it together in bash:

```
dirs=`ls $PWD/Folder1`
for dir in ${dirs[*]}; do
    if [ ! -e $PWD/Folder2/$dir ]; then
        echo "$dir missing"
    fi
done
```

I make no claim that this is an ideal solution, but since I'm also learning bash, I'd be interested to hear why this is a particularly good or bad way to go about it.

Comment: The OP is on a Windows machine, which means that `$PWD` is very likely to contain spaces (`Documents and Settings`, `Program Files`, etc.), so you really need to take care to avoid incorrect word splitting. (Actually you should take care to avoid incorrect word splitting even on Unix/Linux boxes -- spaces in filenames are legal there, too -- but on Windows that goes threefold.)

Comment: Also, you apparently read the original question better than herby or I did: I hadn't noticed that the question doesn't actually ask about comparing the directories recursively!

Comment: @ruakh Well that was at least the original question, but the comments make my answer obsolete. 

Thanks for the point about spaces in the directory names. I should definitely be more careful about that.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want only one level of nesting, you can do this:

```
(cd Folder1 && find -type d -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1) >list1
(cd Folder2 && find -type d -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1) >list2
while read dir; do
    fgrep -qx "$dir" list2 || echo "\"$dir\" has been deleted"
done <list1
```

If you are sure only to have directories in both folders, replace the `find` commands with a simple `ls`.